# How to use sqrt function in sqlite query in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have this code:

```kotlin
// select all venues where distance to theme is less than 1km
@Query("SELECT * FROM Venue WHERE SQRT(((lat-:lat)*(lat-:lat))+((lng-:lng)*(lng-:lng)))<1000.0 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 30 OFFSET :offset")
fun getVenues(lat: Double, lng: Double, offset: Int): Flow<List<Venue>>
```

But I'm facing this error:

```
2021-02-23 00:38:51.419 30376-30510 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such function: SQRT
```

what should I do for using SQRT in android sqlite?

Comment: @user15244370 I saw that before, but I can't use 3rd party in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just let it squared `lat*lat+lon*lon < 1000000.0` (1000 * 1000)

Comment: It wasn't what I excepted but it was very useful solution; I will accept this answer. thanks a lot